# push_front method C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, c++11, nodes

I am given a list class that has a `Node` inner class. Here is the inner class:

```
class Node
{
public:
    /**
     * The constructor
     * @param data the data to be stored in this node
     */
    explicit Node( const Object& data )
      : data( data ), next( NULL ) {}

    Object data;
    Node * next;
};
```

We are told to write a `push_front` method that will push an element to the front of a list. I am having some trouble coming up with the correct way to do this. The `list` class has 3 private attributes: `uint size`, `Node * first`, and `Node * last`

The way I am thinking the `push_front` should work is this: if the list is currently empty (that is `size = 0`) then whatever object we are trying to push should become the last element on that list. Any other element we try to push will become the first and point to the next node.

```
void push_front( const Object& item )
{
    Node * new_node = new Node( item );

    if ( size == 0 )
    {
        new_node = last;
    }
    else
    {
        Node * temp = first;
        first->data = new_node;
        first->next = temp;
    }
```

I can't help but feel like this isn't the right way to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest how I can do this the right way? Thanks.
    }

Comment: Can you elaborate on your feeling that something's not right?

Comment: i'd also suggest removing the c++11 tag unless you specifically want to target c++11 features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
Node * new_node = new Node( item );

if ( size == 0 )
{
    new_node = last;
}
```

are clearly problematic. You've allocated an object, but if the list was empty, you're throwing it away. It doesn't make much sense.

You're also not updating `size` anywhere, so that's a problem too.

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
void push_front( const Object& item )
{
    Node * new_node = new Node( item );
    ++size;

    if ( size == 1 )
    {
        new_node->next = nullptr;
        first = last = new_node;
        return;
    }

    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;
}
```

Comment: How come we are preincrementing? Should we only modify `size` after we have pushed something on the list? In other words, could we have `size++` come at the end and the if-statement be `if ( size == 0 )`?

Comment: @GenericUser01 "pushing something on the list" did not start before the function starts, has ended by the function's end, and is in an indeterminate state within the function. Within the function, you can update `size` wherever you want, basically.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

- construct a new node on the heap
- if `size == 0` make **both** `first` and `last` both point to the new node, otherwise assign the current `first` to `new_node->next` and make `first` point to what `new_node` points to
- increment `size`

Your code stops making sense at `new_node = last;` (you have just leaked memory, don't care about `first`?), there's also type mismatch at:

```
first->data = new_node;
```

Comment: My thinking was, "If the list is empty, that is `size = 0`, then make this new element the last element in the list. After that any new element that is pushed on the list cannot be the last, it can only become the first element." As for incrementing size, that was a typo. I was typing without paying attention and meant to put that in but forgot.

Comment: As for the code segment in the else body, I was trying to create a temporary node that held the current contents of `first`, then change the contents of first so that it contains the information in `new_node`, then have the `new_node` (which is now `first`) point to the previous element. That's at least what I was attempting to try to do.